# Why there is database connection issue in RNCEP package

Tags: r

I am trying to use "RNCEP" package in R studio. I ran following code

```
install.packages("RNCEP", dependencies=TRUE)
library(RNCEP)

wx.extent <- NCEP.gather(variable= 'air', level=850, months.minmax=c(8,9), 
    years.minmax=c(2006,2007), lat.southnorth=c(50,55), lon.westeast=c(0,5), 
    reanalysis2 = FALSE, return.units = TRUE)
```

I got error messages as:

> trying URL
>   'http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis/pressure/air.2006.nc.das'
>   Content length 660 bytes
>
> Error in NCEP.gather.pressure(variable = variable, months.minmax =
>   months.minmax,  :
>
> There is a problem connecting to the NCEP database with the
>   information provided.
>
> Try entering
>   http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis/pressure/air.2006.nc.das
>   into a web browser to obtain an error message.

In addition: Warning messages:

> 1: In
>   download.file(paste("http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis",
>   :   cannot open URL
>   'http://www.cfauth.com/?cfru=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5lc3JsLm5vYWEuZ292L3BzZC90aHJlZGRzL2RvZHNDL0RhdGFzZXRzL25jZXAucmVhbmFseXNpcy9wcmVzc3VyZS9haXIuMjAwNi5uYy5kYXM=':
>   HTTP status was '401 Unauthorized'

Please suggest me the correct syntax to download NCEP data.
Thanks
Sam

Comment: Did you do what it said and try entering that website into a browser?

Comment: Yes, there is lines of code exist in the web browser when I enter the link that it suggested. There is no any error messages.